# filtering list based on two different data columns linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

How do I filter an item from a list based on two different columns one being a number(smallest number) using LINQ C#?

```
public class Line
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }


  public Line()
  {
    LineItems = new List<LineItem> {
    new LineItem{Num = 1, Name="i", Qty = 0, Active = false},
    new LineItem{Num = 2, Name="j", Qty = 2,Active = false},
    new LineItem{Num = 3, Name="k", Qty = 3,Active = false},
     };
  }

}

public class LineItem
{
   public int Num { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Qty { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I want to filter this list and get a LineItem based on Qty = 0 and smallest num value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filtering by `Qty == 0`, sorting according to `Num` and keep the first one:

```
var lineItem = LineItems.Where(l => l.Qty == 0).OrderBy(l => l.Num).FirstOrDefault();
```

or just keep the first that `Qty` equals to `0` and `Num` equals to minimum possible:

```
var minNum = LineItems.Where(l => l.Qty == 0).Min(l => l.Num);
var lineItem = LineItems.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Qty == 0 && l.Num == minNum);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. However what if I have a collection that has two or more items with Qty = 0. Like this one...                                                    ' 'public Line()
  {
    LineItems = new List<LineItem> {
    new LineItem{Num = 1, Name="i", Qty = 1, Active = false},
    new LineItem{Num = 2, Name="j", Qty = 0,Active = false},
    new LineItem{Num = 3, Name="k", Qty = 0,Active = false},
     };
  }'

Comment: @codeFazal: In the linq you are keeping the items with `Qty == 0`, may be more than one, but after that, you will take only one with the minimum `Num` value

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the min value for `Qty` is `0` and order by `Num` in ascending mode, then taking the first item. For sample:

```
var item = LineItems.Where(x => x.Qty == 0).OrderBy(x => x.Num).First();
```

Comment: I had to chose @Arturo Menchaca even though you both have given the same answer, because of the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your LineItem class implement `IComparable<T>`, then you can do something like this:

```
public class LineItem : IComparable<LineItem>
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(LineItem other)
    {
        if (other.Num > this.Num)
            return -1;
        else if (other.Num == this.Num)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;

    }
}
```

then

```
var item = l.LineItems.Where(p => p.Qty == 0).Min();
```